# How to Password Protect whole site except for some subdirectories

Tags: customization, themes, security, password

I'm currently using the [Password Protected](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/password-protected/) plugin to hide my whole website behind a password, I'm doing this because the site is still in development and so we don't want anyone to be able to see it.

However, we've now got to the point where we want the blog section of the website to not be password protected. The issue I have is that the plugin doesn't let you whitelist any URLs, everything is password protected or nothing at all it seems.

Wordpress lives on the root of our site (www.example.com) and our blog is in the subdirectory "blog" (www.example.com/blog/). I'm using the [Multiple Themes Plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/) to be able to have our custom theme for the main website and a separate theme for the blog. I don't know if that's relevant but maybe it is?

I've never made a wordpress website that uses multiple themes like this before and so I'm a bit lost as to how I can solve this problem. Is there a way to have anything other than "www.example.com/blog/" in the password protected area but "www.example.com/blog/" is allowed to be viewed publically?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: sounds like your setup sucks. you should have probably used two different wordpress installs, or multisite.maybe it is not too late to change how you do things.

Comment: Well it only sucks because this is temporary. The main site is only going to be behind a password-protected section while it's still in beta, in a few weeks time it'll be live. But then we decided we want the blog to be live earlier so we can start to get the word out. So yeah, using one wordpress install and multiple themes actually works great if we didn't need to password protect some parts and not others, which is something that has come up since. The problem with having 2 wordpress installs is that then we have 2 different dashboards which isn't ideal, but if it's the only way then ok.

Comment: it sucks because you are using plugins to recreate functionality which is better achieved in other ways. The password protection is probably just the first challenge you are going to face.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is the only challenge I will face because in a few weeks time we will be getting rid of that plugin anyway. We are just keeping the website private while we're still testing it, yet we want the other part public. Can you help me out with the "better achieved in other ways" part then please?